# Storage nightmare

Tags: insufficient-memory

I've known my phone's been pretty full for a while (mainly music, which is seemingly impossible to save to my SD card), but the equalizer on the music app I use recently started acting up. I went onto Google Play to give it a shit review, but then realised it needed an update. When I tried the update, it told me I had insufficient storage space, so I decided to delete the app to see if it would have been updated if I downloaded it again. Insufficient storage space. I've now deleted four fairly large apps from my phone, and guess what my phone told me when I tried to download the music app again? Yep... Insufficient storage space! Still. And now I've got no apps either... Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Wow, looks you've got some "shitty downvotes" (hint: 1. if something "acts up", before giving bad ratings at Playstore better check if it's not your fault; 2. have you used our nice search function to check for similar issues?). To get you started nevertheless, I've re-tagged your question. Please check our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for first aid and useful links. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

your storage issue is widely encountered within the android devices users.Although you didn't mention your device name and android version,you should look for your microSD card if it is mounted read/write or read only and see your internal SD card too.Google has restricted the ability to write to the SD card for Android KitKat and above so you have to try to use Kitkat SDFix from Play Store to restore this great feature.If this doesn't work you might try to root your device and install the Xposed framework and then download a module called "HandleExternalStorage" from within the Xposed installer,activate it and reboot your phone or tablet.